# AJAX Get isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to pull data from a mysql server with AJAX. 
This is the AJAX call:

```
function getAllTasks()
        {
            alert("Getting all tasks");

            $.ajax({
              type: "get",
              url: "ajax.php",
              dataType: "json",
              data: data,
              async: false,
              success: function(data){
                   alert('hi!');
                   //perform operation
                },
                error: function() {
                  alert('Error occurs!');
                }
            });
        }
```

and this is the PHP it's supposed to run:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');



$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'projectAdmin', 'admin', 'to_do_list')
    or die('Error connection to database');

    getAllTasks($conn);




function getAllTasks($conn)
{
$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE ID=1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tasks[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($tasks);

}
```

It's not working. When I run the PHP alone, it works fine, and returns a JSON string in the browser (chrome).
When I run the AJAX, nothing happens. I get the "getting all tasks" alert, and then it just doesn't work. The AJAX is called from the $(document).ready() function.

I don't know where I'm going wrong, I've looked at a bunch of posts on here and my AJAX code looks next to identical. Is it an issue with json_encode? The AJAX? 
Help, please.

Comment: `data` is not defined, have you check your js error ?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
data: data,
```

It looks that the `data` variable is undefined. Also I would recommend you removing the `async: false` option in order to make an asynchronous request instead of blocking the UI.

Looking at the `Console` in your browser might also reveal some potential problems with your code.

Comment: And use `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the data variable? Is it to hold what's returned or to pass data to the PHP?

Comment: It's to pass some parameters to the script. For example if you wanted to call `ajax.php?foo=bar&baz=bazinga`, your `data` parameter might have looked like this: `data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 'bazinga' }`. You will get the result of your script in the `data` argument that your `success` callback takes.

Comment: That was my problem, including "data: data", because now it's succeeding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "ajax.php");
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(ev) {
    var xhr = ev.target;
    if (xhr.readyState < 4) { /*not finished downloading yet.*/
        return;
    }
    /*the request is completed. do your stuff with xhr.responseText here.*/
    console.log(xhr);
});
xhr.send();
```